# What would be the C code to draw a cylinder between 2 3D vectors in OpenGL? I want it to get proportionally bigger as it is closer to viewer

Tags: c, opengl, 3d, opengl-compat, quad

I'm trying to implement a quad function to draw lines. My goal is to be able to display a beam from one 3D spot to another. But I'm failing at it. Also I want to be able to specify a 3D thickness parameter in the function that draws the quad/cylinder. Do I need to draw a cylinder? if not, how do I set the 4 3D quad corner coordinates? I first tried with a quad but figured what I really needed was a cylinder, see the code in my answer, works just fine, and doesn't even use GLU at all, raw C. I edited this question, because my initial code was confussing and weird. My answer works, I repeat. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you need to do some debugging. This code alone doesn't really help.

Comment: The problem is that I'm no good at vector math or angles, i don't need to debug, I just need to know the math involved in getting the 4 3d coords for the quad, or how to draw a cylinder between 2 3d vectors

Comment: To make a line I'd figure that the length of the line might factor in somewhere, but I don't see that in your code. You'll presumably need both the normalized vector along the line, plus one orthogonal to that, which involves a rotation by 90°, also not shown.

Comment: This code would be a lot easier to read if you were using a vector math library where you could do `a = b - c` where those are all vectors. Working this way is not really fun at all, especially if you have to do matrix transformations. It's worth noting that a lot of 3D code uses 4x4 matrices and XYZW vectors accordingly as then you can do a ton of stuff with matrix transforms not easy with 3x3 matrices.

Comment: Ok, but can you post a code example guys? I guess what i need is a cylinder, but the examples I've found on google doesn't allow setting it along 2 3d coords

Comment: If you're doing a line in 3D space you'll probably have to take into account the camera position as well, otherwise the width will be unpredictable. You'll have to orient the line's "up" vector towards the camera. If you want it consistent width you may also need to project it onto a flat plane in front of the camera, then "draw" it there.

Comment: I've found this example but it uses glu, i need raw C! https://github.com/curran/renderCyliner/blob/master/renderCylinder.c

Comment: thanks tadman, but i don't know how to do that, need C code

Comment: I used the code in this java example to draw a cylinder and it's fine for me now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878257/how-can-i-draw-a-cylinder-that-connects-two-points-in-opengl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the adapted (from java) 'raw' C code I'm using to draw the cylinder:

```
void getFirstPerpVector(float x, float y, float z, vec3_t result) 
{
    result[0] = result[1] = result[2] = 0.0f;
    // That's easy.
    if (x == 0.0f || y == 0.0f || z == 0.0f) {
        if (x == 0.0f)
            result[0] = 1.0f;
        else if (y == 0.0f)
            result[1] = 1.0f;
        else
            result[2] = 1.0f;
    }
    else {
        // If xyz is all set, we set the z coordinate as first and second argument .
        // As the scalar product must be zero, we add the negated sum of x and y as third argument
        result[0] = z;      //scalp = z*x
        result[1] = z;      //scalp = z*(x+y)
        result[2] = -(x + y); //scalp = z*(x+y)-z*(x+y) = 0
        // Normalize vector
        float length = 0.0f;
        
        length += result[0] * result[0];
        length += result[1] * result[1];
        length += result[2] * result[2];

        length = (float)sqrt(length);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            result[i] /= length;
    }    
}

void drawCylinder(float x1, float y1, float z1, float x2, float y2, float z2, float thick, col_t color) 
{
    int X = 0,
        Y = 1,
        Z = 2;
    // Get components of difference vector
    float x = x1 - x2,
        y = y1 - y2,
        z = z1 - z2;
    vec3_t firstPerp;
    getFirstPerpVector(x, y, z, firstPerp);
    // Get the second perp vector by cross product
    vec3_t secondPerp;
    secondPerp[X] = y * firstPerp[Z] - z * firstPerp[Y];
    secondPerp[Y] = z * firstPerp[X] - x * firstPerp[Z];
    secondPerp[Z] = x * firstPerp[Y] - y * firstPerp[X];
    // Normalize vector
    float length = 0.0f;
    
    length += secondPerp[0] * secondPerp[0];
    length += secondPerp[1] * secondPerp[1];
    length += secondPerp[2] * secondPerp[2];

    length = (float)sqrt(length);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        secondPerp[i] /= length;

    // Having now our vectors, here we go:
    // First points; you can have a cone if you change the radius R1
    int ANZ = C_CYLINDER_NUM_VERTICES;  // number of vertices Original 32
    float FULL = (float)(2.0f * M_PI),
        R1 = thick;// 2.0f; // radius Original 4.0f
    
    float points[C_CYLINDER_NUM_VERTICES + 1][3]; // 32 was ANZ
    for (int i = 0; i < ANZ; i++) {
        float angle = FULL * (i / (float)ANZ);

        points[i][X] = (float)(R1 * (cos(angle) * firstPerp[X] + sin(angle) * secondPerp[X]));
        points[i][Y] = (float)(R1 * (cos(angle) * firstPerp[Y] + sin(angle) * secondPerp[Y]));
        points[i][Z] = (float)(R1 * (cos(angle) * firstPerp[Z] + sin(angle) * secondPerp[Z]));
    }
    // Set last to first
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        points[ANZ][x] = points[0][x];
    
    glColor4ubv(color);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glVertex3f(x1, y1, z1);
    for (int i = 0; i <= ANZ; i++) {
        glVertex3f(x1 + points[i][X],
            y1 + points[i][Y],
            z1 + points[i][Z]);
    }
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glVertex3f(x2, y2, z2);
    for (int i = 0; i <= ANZ; i++) {
        glVertex3f(x2 + points[i][X],
            y2 + points[i][Y],
            z2 + points[i][Z]);
    }
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
    for (int i = 0; i <= ANZ; i++) {
        glVertex3f(x1 + points[i][X],
            y1 + points[i][Y],
            z1 + points[i][Z]);
        glVertex3f(x2 + points[i][X],
            y2 + points[i][Y],
            z2 + points[i][Z]);
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

Comment: Comparing that a value is *precisely* zero is always impractical.

Comment: Well to be honest I don't understand any of the involved math, but the cylinder gets drawn and that's what matters to me ^_^

Comment: I'm just saying that there are zero-ish values you'll encounter that are like `1.0e-39` or something trivially tiny which is not literally `==0.0f`. These result from things like rotations or translations where tiny errors are introduced. Often you'll need to do `if (abs(x) < 1.0e-20)` or some safe [epsilon value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon). If you ever encounter a bug like this it will be extremely frustrating to reproduce and fix, which is why preventing it is important.